# How to Fill a Detected Plane with Point Clouds using Open3D?

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I have used Open3D to detect a plane from a point cloud data. Now, I want to fill this detected plane with point clouds. I am interested in generating new points on this plane and adding them to the existing point cloud.

Here is what I have done so far:

http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/pointcloud.html#Planar-patch-detection

```py
dataset = o3d.data.PCDPointCloud()
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(dataset.path)
assert (pcd.has_normals())

# using all defaults
oboxes = pcd.detect_planar_patches(
    normal_variance_threshold_deg=60,
    coplanarity_deg=75,
    outlier_ratio=0.75,
    min_plane_edge_length=0,
    min_num_points=0,
    search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamKNN(knn=30))

print("Detected {} patches".format(len(oboxes)))
```

Is there a specific method in Open3D to accomplish this, or do I need to write custom code to generate points on the detected plane and add them to my point cloud? Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you!